# How to remove sharing in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-sharing

I have prepared a Google Sheets spreadsheet for another person.

He has asked me: How can he remove the shared status in the spreadsheet I have sent him. He wants to it to be single-owned by him thus not as a shared file.

How to stop sharing the spreadsheet?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. There are basically two options transfer the ownership of the spreadsheet or make a copy. For further details, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

They can make their own copy via the file menu:

[image]

or (ask you to) change the share settings with the share button in the top bar:

[image]

Just as you can *add* viewers/editors there, you can remove them as well, as shown in §3.2 [here](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9305987?hl=en):

> #### Stop sharing a file or folder you own:
>
> 1. Open the homescreen for Google Drive, Google Docs, Google Sheets, or Google Slides.
> 2. Select a file or folder.
> 3. Click Share or Share Share.
> 4. Find the person you want to stop sharing with.
> 5. To the right of their name, click the Down arrow Down and then Remove.
> 6. To save changes, click Save.

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel. That was just what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome! Please note that you can [accept](/help/someone-answers) it by clicking the checkmark below its score.